How to remove grey overlay screen on top of ViewPager2 fragmentandroid
I am facing a problem with viewpager2
I have parentViewPager2 with Fragments like FragmentA, FragmentB ...
and FragmentA also have ViewPager2 with Fragments like InnerFragment1 InnerFragment2 Nested
it was working fine until migrate to ViewPager2 my problem is that it is working fine but showing grey overlay screen on top ViewPager it disappear while touching on screen
here is My ParentViewPager2 xml
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/fragments_bg">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/title_linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/edittext_height"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/constituents_title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3.6"
            android:fontFamily="@font/helvetica_new_light"
            android:gravity="center|start"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_12sdp"
            android:textColor="@color/sub_title_color"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1.5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/fragments_bg"
            android:visibility="gone">

        </View>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".4"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/option_relative"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/white">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/options"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/down_arrow_holding"
                    android:tint="@color/colorPrimary" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1.5dp"
        android:background="@color/fragments_bg"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_linear" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sub_title_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/edittext_height"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:weightSum="4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3.6">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sub_title_tv"
                style="@style/style_semibold_fontsize_14"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="3.6"
                android:fontFamily="@font/helvetica_light"
                android:gravity="center|start"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_12sdp"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/sub_title_color" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1.5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/fragments_bg" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/subtext_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".4"
            android:background="@color/fragments_bg">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/create_new_img"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/white">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/filter_imgview"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/sort_filter"
                    android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:visibility="visible" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/fragments_bg"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sub_title_linear_layout" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sub_title_linear_layout_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sub_title_tv_2"
                style="@style/style_fontsize_14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/down_arrow_expand"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/helvetica_light"
                android:gravity="center|start"
                android:padding="@dimen/_6sdp"
                android:text="Performance Year: 2021"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1.5dp"
        android:background="@color/fragments_bg"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sub_title_linear_layout_2" />


    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view3">

    </androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2>





    <ProgressBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/common_dark_gray_color"
        android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

here is my childViewPager2 inside the ParentViewPager2
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/title_linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/edittext_height"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/constituents_title"
            android:fontFamily="@font/helvetica_new_light"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3.6"
            android:gravity="center|start"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_12sdp"
            android:text="@string/lbl_assetbycurrency"
            android:textColor="@color/sub_title_color" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1.5dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/fragments_bg">

        </View>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".4"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/option_relative"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/white">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/options"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/down_arrow_holding"
                    app:tint="@color/colorPrimary" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1.5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title_linear"
        android:background="@color/fragments_bg"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/overview_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="-3.3sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="Skip"
        android:textColor="#999999"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <com.mydesq.mywealth.utils.NestedScrollableHost
        android:id="@+id/viewPager2rl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/pager_dots"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view1">



    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewPager2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible">

    </androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2>
    </com.mydesq.mywealth.utils.NestedScrollableHost>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/pager_dots"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
</RelativeLayout>


Please help is there anyone ?
